# Exchange rates with one rate

Tags: foreign-exchange

*This is not real exchange rates.

When doing exchange rate calculations, and I have only the rate for USD to GBP. can we find the rate for GBP to USD?

let say I have $100
USD to GBP= 0.27
GBP to USD= ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the reciprocal.

1/0.27 = 3.704

Comment: Why downvote? Math is correct is it not?

Comment: Your math is fine.  I wonder if someone's expecting a more complicated answer to a simple question.

Comment: yeah, not sure what's going on, question and answer are both on-topic. There's not much more to be said.

Comment: My guess (though I didn't downvote) is that no one's mentioned the difference between the buy, sell and [mid-market](https://www.kantox.com/en/glossary/mid-market-rate/) rates. If the OP's rate _was_ the mid-market rate, the above figure will be the correct reverse mid-market rate; if the OP's rate is the buy-price for GBP, then the sell price will be different from the above figure.

Comment: But in that case, it should have been made clearer by OP. His question (imo) clearly indicates he is just curious of how to calculate the reverse - nothing fancy regarding buy/sell prices.

Comment: @Steffen I'm happy with your answer; just offering a guess as to why someone might have downvoted.

Comment: @TripeHound - no offense taken; just wanted to make it clear to other readers how I was thinking ;-)